# INSERT summary data of one table into another table

Tags: sql, postgresql, report, aggregate-functions

I am trying to create a summary table based on another table. I have table `a` and I want table `b` to be a record of the status of table `a` monthly.

So every month I want to be able to schedule a job to count how many records appear in `a` and put that number in table `b`

I don't know where to even start with this one.

Comment: So you want to create a job that runs everyone month, It runs a stored procedure that counts the items and table A and then make a log entry into table B ? is the row count the only thing you are trying to gather?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`b` could look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE b (
  ts   timestamptz(0) PRIMARY KEY
, a_ct bigint NOT NULL
);
```

Then run your query any convenient time:

```
INSERT INTO b (ts, a_ct)
SELECT now(), count(*) FROM a;
```

Comment: Any way this could be manipulated to sum a field? This is glorious

Comment: @lemoney: Sure: `sum(my_field)`. Start by reading the manual here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES

Comment: Awesome to know all the aggregates are accepted! thanks so much!